# SQL WHERE BETWEEN not selecting all data

Tags: excel, vb.net, ms-access, export-to-excel

I've written an export (Access to Excel) function in an application that works in ranges.

The user has 4 `RadioButtons`: A-F, G-M, N-R and S-Z.

Let's say the user has selected `rbtnAF`, which will load all customers into the grid where the `Customer_Code` field starts with an A, B, C, D, E or F.

The code to load in the data is as follows:

```
Dim strFields As String = "[Customer_Addresses].[Cust_Code], [Customers].[Customer_Name], [Customer_Addresses].[Contact_Code], [Customer_Addresses].[Contact_Name], " & _
        "[Customer_Addresses].[Contact_Type], [Customer_Addresses].[Add1], [Customer_Addresses].[Add2], [Customer_Addresses].[Add3], [Customer_Addresses].[Add4], " & _
        "[Customer_Addresses].[Add5], [Customer_Addresses].[Postcode], [Customer_Addresses].[Country], [Customer_Addresses].[Telephone], [Customer_Addresses].[Fax], " & _
        "[Customer_Addresses].[Email], [Customer_Addresses].[Mobile_Phone], [Customers].[Customer_Category], [Customers].[Average_Payment_Terms], " & _
        "[Customers].[Notes], [Customers].[salesRep], [Customers].[hoEmail], [Customers].[webpage] FROM Customers " & _
        "INNER JOIN Customer_Addresses ON [Customers].[Customer_Code] =[Customer_Addresses].[Cust_Code]"

    If rbtnAF.Checked = True Then
        sql = "SELECT " & strFields & " WHERE [Customer_Addresses].[Cust_Code] BETWEEN " & _
        "'A*' AND 'F*' ORDER BY [Customer_Addresses].[Cust_Code]"

        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)

        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim dt As New System.Data.DataTable

        da.Fill(ds)
        dt = ds.Tables(0).Copy()

        ugExport.DataSource = Nothing
        ugExport.DataSource = dt
```

This was, I thought, working fine, I was able to load the correct ranges into the grid and export them as I wanted. 
However, the user has come back to me and said it's not loading all customers.

I thought this was a bit weird, so I loaded up their database and tested it for myself. In the DB, there are 4 customers who fit into the range of A-F, as you can see in this image.

[image]

However, when I then view the customer range A-F in the export list, there are only 2 customers displayed.

[image]

It's also worth noting, in the Customer List screen there is a `TextBox` to allow the user to search by customer code - When I type in just a single F, all 4 customers are displayed as expected.

What on Earth is going on to only display 2 of the results in the Export List, despite there being 4 records that fit the criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the between syntax you will find that it treats * as a literal character see here https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Between-And-Operator-a435878d-63f7-4825-8c31-999432ae8223

You can use

```
Like "[A-F]*"
```

Instead though.